Excel: IF function, multiple ranges and conditions
I'm trying to make my life easier, but my lack of Excel skills keep me from doing that.
I have a few ranges of values:
1 - 100.000
100.001 - 250.000
250.001 - 1.000.000
1.000.001 - 1.000.000.000

Based on the value I input by hand, which is in one of these range, I need to calculate the percentage of it: 1%, 0.8%, 0.6%, respectively 0.4%, depending in which range I am.
I also have a minimum value to adjust by for each ranges: 750, 1000, 2000, 6000; and need to compare this minimul value with the percentage from above, and select which one is higher, and extract that value to put in another table.
If possible, I'd want to have all this in only one cell, so I can make that final table easier to read.
I've managed to achieve the result by doing alot more steps:
Example:

Input by hand: I1
E2= `=IF(AND($I$1>=A2,$I$1<=B2),$I$1*C2,"")` - similar for E3-E5
F2= `=IF(E2<D2,D2,E2)` - similar for F3-F5
I2 = `=IF(F2<>"",F2,IF(F3<>"",F3,IF(F4<>"",F4,F5)))`

But considering that my real list has alot more of ranges depending on the application, I need a formula for only one cell:
Input number: I2
Result: I3

Why not using IFS() as you have multiple conditions?

This formula can help you:
J2 =TAKE(FILTER(B2:D5,I1<=B2:B5),1)


In I2, you need to use K1 and L1 for calculation.
You can put the formula to any cell then hide that row or those columns to maintain the layout.
If you don't need the calculation numbers anywhere else, you can avoid of using the intermediate range and use the only formula in the target cell:
I2 =LET(c,FILTER(C2:D5,I1<=B2:B5),MAX(I1*INDEX(c,1,1),INDEX(c,1,2)))

where the last argument "MAX(I1*INDEX(c,1,1),INDEX(c,1,2))" is your required calculation.

You have a lookup table, use it:
=MAX(INDEX(C2:C5,MATCH(I1,A2:A5))*I1,INDEX(D2:D5,MATCH(I1,A2:A5)))


(note that the "max" column is superfluous here)

=LET(i,MATCH(I1,A2:A5),MAX(INDEX(C2:C5,i)*I1,INDEX(D2:D5,i))

Short, using XLOOKUP [match_mode]: 1 - Exact match. If none found, return the next larger item.:
=MAX(HSTACK($I$1, 1) * XLOOKUP($I$1, B2:B5, C2:D5, , 1))

With LET:
=LET(
    table, B2:D5,
    number, I1,
    MAX(
        HSTACK(number, 1) *
            XLOOKUP(number, TAKE(table, , 1), DROP(table, , 1), , 1)
    )
)


